# How WebLogic Managed servers shared the JDBC resources and maximum capacity?

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, connection-pooling, weblogic12c, capacity

I have a WebLogic 12C instance with 1 admin server and 5 Managed servers. One of my application is using "XYZ" data source (Type: GENERIC)
This DS is targeting to all servers in the cluster i.e. admin + managed servers.

In Connection pool section, if I give the Maximum Capacity=50, does it mean WebLogic will allow 50 connections per server i.e. 50*5 or 50*6? Or it is maximum capacity for all servers in the cluster i.e. 50 distributed in all 6 servers? Is the same property applicable for other parameters like minimum capacity, statement cache?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum capacity is set per server. Then, you will get 250 or 300 sql connections on your database.